# Does C automatically free char * return if I use it for another function?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I have a function called combine that combines two strings, potentially with a / when I use it for file path combinations:

```
char* combine(const char* input1, const char* input2, int slash) {
    char* output = malloc(512);
    if (slash)
        sprintf(output, "%s/%s", input1, input2);
    else 
        sprintf(output, "%s%s", input1, input2);
    return output;
}
```

I then call this function directly in many cases and input right into another such as:

`mkdir(combine(localname, "metadata", 1), 0700);`

Will the memory allocated for combine(); be freed afterward? I use this method of coding instead of assigning the combine() output to a local variable and freeing it because it looks much nicer, and it's easier to read, but if this is going to cause memory leaks I will stop.

Comment: No, it will not be freed, it is a memory leak.

Comment: Most user operating systems will release allocated memory once the process (the program) ends. If you want dynamically allocated memory released while the program is running, you need to explicitly `free` it.

Comment: The code also risks buffer overflows. You should be using snprintf and at least PATH_MAX as buffer size or allocate the buffer to always fit.

Comment: It is better to use `pathconf`.

Answer (score 0):

No,

```
mkdir(combine(localname, "metadata", 1), 0700);
```

will pass the alloced pointer to `mkdir`, and then it is lost, so you get memory leak.

---

There are at least two ways to solve this

1. Return pointer to a static buffer (or static pointer to a single `malloc` buffer, so there is just one "memory leaked" block), which will be re-used every call. Bad for multi-threaded apps, and you need to take a copy (like with `strdup`) if you need to store the buffer accross multiple calls, so you have to be careful with nested calls using the function. Not recommended.
2. Pass the buffer as parameter, return pointer to it, much like `strncat`.